# ¿Por qué no funciona background-color?

Tags: css

```css
.body{
  background-color: red;
  color:red;
  font-family:Arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="CSS10.css">
<title>Web ejercicio 10</title>
</head>

<body "body">
    <div class="div1">
        <p><a href="">P&aacute;gina Principal</a></p>
        <p><a href="">Enlace 1</a></p>
        <p><a href="">Enlace 2</a></p>
        <p><a href="">Enlace 3</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

He comprobado que el archivo se nombraba igual y no consigo hacerlo funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes mal tu HTML. `<body "body">` no es válido. Además en tu CSS estás haciendo referencia a la clase `body` (poniendo el selector punto (.) antes del nombre `body`).

O bien quitas "body" de tu elemento  y quitas el punto en el CSS:

```css
body{
  background-color: red;
  color:red;
  font-family:Arial;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="CSS10.css">
<title>Web ejercicio 10</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="div1">
    <p><a href="">P&aacute;gina Principal</a></p>
    <p><a href="">Enlace 1</a></p>
    <p><a href="">Enlace 2</a></p>
    <p><a href="">Enlace 3</a></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

O bien añades una clase "body" a tu elemento `<body class="body">`

```css
.body{
  background-color: red;
  color:red;
  font-family:Arial;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="CSS10.css">
<title>Web ejercicio 10</title>
</head>

<body class="body">
  <div class="div1">
    <p><a href="">P&aacute;gina Principal</a></p>
    <p><a href="">Enlace 1</a></p>
    <p><a href="">Enlace 2</a></p>
    <p><a href="">Enlace 3</a></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Todo dependerá de tus necesidades pero piensa que  engloba a todo por lo que las propiedades que le asignes son generales.